# how to find the output for a file if head number and tail number is given

Tags: sort, tail, head

If file `foo` contains 9 lines, each of which is the one-digit line number of the line in the file (1 through 9), what is the output on your screen of this command:

```
sort foo foo | tail -2 | head -1
```

The answer is 9 but what I don't understand is how they got it.
What does the `sort` command actually do?

Likewise, if `foo` contains 99 lines, each of which is the two-digit line number of the line in the file (01 through 99), what should be the output of this command:

```
sort -r foo foo | tail -4 | head -1
```

Comment: Trying the `sort` command yourself would have enabled you to find this out directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) sort "sort[s] lines of text files". This is clearly a trick question to test basic knowledge and not to accomplish anything. as `tail -1 foo` has the same output.

```
> echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9" > foo
> sort foo
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
> sort foo foo
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
9
> sort foo foo | tail -2
9
9
> sort foo foo | tail -2 | head -1
9
```

if you missed that foo was passed twice you might think the answer 8 or if you had no idea what any of the commands did you would not be able to answer the question beyond guessing.